# Can you please explain the output of this C program?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int b = 10;
    char ch = 33^b&1;
    for(;"what"[b+++21];)
    printf("%c",ch);
}
```

The output of this code is two ! signs.

I am unable to comprehend how is it working and what is the meaning of condition statement of for loop ("what"[b+++21]).

Why the loop is running only two times ?

Comment: I think this program will cause out-of-range array access and the output will be indeterminate.

Comment: `+++` is parsed as `++ +`  . If you still don't understand  , try to be more specific

Comment: @MikeCAT out of range array access causes undefined behaviour

Comment: Debugger may help explaining this specific result, but it may change the result.

Comment: Output can't be two signs, as there is only one printed char. and condition of the for loop is undefined behavior (index outside array length).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Well that's why it is undefined :) . On my system it give 4 `!`  signs printed

Comment: Ultimately this is reading 52 bytes ahead in your program's stack and looking for bytes that are 0. it will exit when it finds one, in the meanwhile it will print the character (33) `!`. I'm not sure in anyway what this program hopes to achieve.

Comment: Ok, I missed the point that printf was in the scope of the for-loop... Sorry.

Comment: @MikeCAT: There is use trying to understand undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is a XY problem. You need to tell us why you need to understand it.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: the `printf` is the body of the `for` loop.  Lack of indentation is part of the obfuscation, I suppose.  Undefined behavior might be the intended discussion topic, but it I'm not sure.

Comment: What a complete pile of utter..... homework:(

Comment: @user3528438, I have seen this code on quora and was not able to understand why it was behaving in mentioned way.

Comment: @niks2010 Quora?  OK, please provide a link:)

Comment: @MartinJames  https://www.quora.com/What-is-your-favorite-piece-of-code/answer/Utsav-Deep   :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code has undefined behavior, it may print 2 `!` on your system, but it may do something entirely different on a different system, and indeed I don't want to be flying a plane that runs it on its navigation system.

Reformatting the code makes it a little more explicit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int b = 10;
    char ch = 33 ^ b & 1;
    for (;"what"[b++ + 21];)
        printf("%c", ch);
}
```

Here is what is happening:

- `b` is initialized with value `10`.
- `ch` is initialized with value `(33 ^ (b & 1))`.  Since `10` is even, `b & 1` is `0`, so `ch` has value `33`, in hex: `0x21`, which is the character `!` in ASCII.
- the `for` loops checks the value of an element from the string literal `"what"`, which is an array of 5 `char` with values `{ 'w', 'h', 'a', 't', 0 }`.  The index is computed as `b++ + 21`.  The first value is `31`, and `b` is incremented to `11`.  Here you have **undefined behavior** because you are referencing the 32nd element of a 5 byte array.

Anything can happen. Reading this byte from memory can cause a crash or just return some random value. Further iterations of the loop dig deeper into the unknown.  On your computer it takes 2 iterations to find a null byte, so the `printf` is run twice, but on some other machine or just some other time, anything could happen.

This test is bogus, a more reliable alternative would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int b=10,ch=33^b&1;
    for(;"what"[b+++-8];)
    printf("%c",ch);
}
```